# Why is my CASE statement requiring the THEN part to be of data type INT?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a query where the below CASE statement is one of the lines. I'm using Report Builder 3.0.

However, I get an error that says :

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Case 1' to data type int; Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 245".

Why is the CASE statement requiring the THEN part to be an INT data type ?

```
  (CASE
            WHEN    jobs.Uf_Production_Line = 'LN BM6'
                    THEN 'Case 1'
            ELSE

            99999
        END
    ) AS line
```

Comment: For which field you are selecting the value is int type.
Understand the Query first.

Comment: @Mayur: While editing question, that is how the error message should be specified and not as code block

Comment: @RagingBull okay thanks for guiding me. Its appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `CASE` statement, all result expressions must have the same data type. If not, the result will be converted to the data type with a higher precedence. According to [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

And since `INT` has a higher [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) than `VARCHAR`, your query produces an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Case 1' to data
>   type int; Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 245".

To fix this, you should convert your `ELSE` part to `VARCHAR`.

```
ELSE '99999'
```

Answer (score 3):

Because your `else` uses a value with data type `int`:

```
ELSE 99999
```

You use data types (`varchar` and `int`) that can't be exchanged automatically.

An option is to use:

```
ELSE '99999'
```

Answer (score 0):

A case statement can only return one data type. So use the number as varchar:

```
(CASE WHEN jobs.Uf_Production_Line = 'LN BM6'
          THEN 'Case 1'
      ELSE '99999'
      END
) AS line
```

**OR** you can return `NULL` instead of 9999 if you want to represent it as an invalid value for `Line`:

```
(CASE WHEN jobs.Uf_Production_Line = 'LN BM6'
          THEN 'Case 1'
      ELSE NULL
      END
) AS line
```

Answer (score 0):

Because **99999** is an `int`. Both cases must return the same data type.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `'99999'` instead of `99999`. All values should be the same datatype in `CASE`, for now in your `ELSE` part values is of `INT` datatype.

Full code should be like:

```
    (CASE WHEN jobs.Uf_Production_Line = 'LN BM6' THEN 'Case 1'
          ELSE '99999'
     END
    ) AS line
```