# Convert Int to time and represent the result as time "HH:mm:ss" (accept more than 24h)

Tags: sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN [FK_PSCategory] < 3 
          THEN CONVERT(char(8), DATEADD(second, (([PS_ProjectInfo].[Length] / 1000 * 60) / DrawingSpeed) * [Quantity], ''), 114)
          ELSE 0 
    END AS ProductionTime 
FROM [dbo].[PS_ProjectInfo]
```

but when I run it I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '00:02:20' to data type int.

I want to represent the result as time HH:mm:ss (and accept more than 24h).

Clarification:

- `[PS_ProjectInfo].[Length] INT` - length in millimeters
- `DrawingSpeed INT` - drawing speed in meters/minute
- `[PS_ProjectInfo].[Length] / 1000` - convert length to meters then multiplied by 60 to convert it into seconds

Comment: The error message tells you that one branch of your `case` returns a varchar and the other returns an int, which you [cannot have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32049306/11683). It has nothing to do with what type of string result you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure your case expression returns the same data type in all eventualities.

Your `else` probably needs to be `'0'` or `'00:00:00'` depending on your requirements.